# Open Source alternatives to ArcGIS Locator Report?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, geocoding

I'm a pretty new GIS programmer and I'm trying to run a [Locator Report](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00mm0000001p000000.htm) in ArcPy with no success.

I'm wondering if there are any other software packages that can accomplish the same thing but with open source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much; you have the ability to download the US Census/Demographics data into your own DB and them extrapolate your own report; there are outside sources of data in the US that commercially massage the data like ESRI does but for a out of the box answer like that you are really limited.